# How to solve this summation in a recursive way

Tags: java, recursion

Today, my teacher asked us to implement the next expression using recursion in Java (where *n* is a value asked to the user):

[image: Summation to be implemented]

It is possible? I can't find a proper solution for this problem, but I think I will need two recursive methods.

## UPDATE

So far I have done this:

```
public static double sumatorio(int n){
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else{
        return (1 + ((n-1) * segundoSumatorio(n))) + sumatorio(n-1);            
    }
}

public static double segundoSumatorio(int n){
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1/(double)n + segundoSumatorio(n-1);
}
```

It looks like it's correct, but **when n=3 or greater, the result is not exact**. Someone knows why?

Maybe there is an error related with losing precision.

[image: Trace]

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You have two different variables named i. It might help you if you change the name of the other i.

Comment: This may be an answer in comment's clothing, but - you are using the wrong limits on the outer sum (you're using 1 to `n` instead of 0 to `n-1`); and you are using `i` in place of `n` in the inner sum (even though you're calling it `n`, it's really `i`).

Comment: This is not precision issue. This is incorrect implementation. But as both your questions are closed I cannot post the fixed code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

1. Yes.  One possible solution *does* involve two recursive methods.

   (And it is a good solution ... )
2. Factor the problem (and the solution) into two parts; e.g. the complete "sigma" and the embedded "sigma".

Comment: Is this a comment in an answer's clothing?

Comment: Thanks, at least this is one valid question. I don't want you to made it for me, just wanted to get some instructions.

Comment: @Bohemian - No.  It is an Answer that points out that he is on the correct track ... and encourages him to keep going on that track.

Comment: @Draco If that is the case, then you should consider accepting this answer with the checkmark symbol, which will give proper answering credit to Mr. Stephen.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your code fixed. Note how the 2nd sumatorio needs 2 parameters,
and how I don't change the second parameter while calling it recursively.
This is what your formula says and not what you implemented.

This is not a precision error, you could have figured that out
because this error sounds too big for a precision error for such
small values of n.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(sumatorio(1));
        System.out.println(sumatorio(2));
        System.out.println(sumatorio(3));
        System.out.println(sumatorio(4));
    }


    public static double sumatorio(int n){
        return sumatorio(n ,n);
    }

    public static double sumatorio(int n, int m){
        if(n==1)
            return 1;
        else{
            return (1 + ((n-1) * segundoSumatorio(m))) + sumatorio(n-1, m);            
        }
    }

    public static double segundoSumatorio(int n){
        if(n==1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 1/(double)n + segundoSumatorio(n-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be probably more intuitive to name your `n` as `i` and `m` as `n`. Also `1/(double)n` can be written shorter as `1d/n`. Anyway this solves OP problem. +1

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, I just wanted to not change too much so OP can find his way in this code.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Today you helped me to understand how to keep the original value of a variable while working with recursive methods.

Answer (score 2):

If this task is too hard for you,  try splitting it in smaller chunks. The question asks for a summation, implemented by recurse. I am confident you can do summation by implementing a loop. Something like:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    sum = sum+i;
}
```

This will sum all numbers from 1 to (n-1).

You can convert the loop into recursion by writing a simple adding method:

```
int sum = 0;

int doSum(int n){
    if(n <= 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return n + doSum(n - 1);
    }
}

sum = doSum(n);
```

From here on I think you should be able to catch up.

Splitting the problem into smaller subproblems is a technique used by ALL programmers. Start small and easy, adding complexity as you go.